# Stationary 2D/3D Navier-Stokes source code

Tags: pde, python, fenics, navier-stokes

Trying to solve stationary Navier-Stokes problem for incompressible laminar Newtonian fluid.

I've found a couple solutions for instationary Navier-Stokes equations (like FeniCS examples or CFD Python), but nothing on stationary.

As far as I understand methods are totally so this code couldn't be reused properly. Does anybody know any software which may help?

Comment: Did you mean "totally different"? There seems to be a word missing.